# Turn a column into two columns using the values of another column (pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
measure   | location  | cause    |  val
Deaths    |  Alabama  |sickness1 | 0.045
Deaths    |  Alabama  |sickness2 | 0.001
...
Prevalence|  Alabama  |sickness1 | 0.05
Prevalence|  Alabama  |sickness2 | 0.003
...
```

So, there are basically two possible measures (Deaths and Prevalence), multiple sicknesses as well as all 51 US states and a value for each.
What I would like to do is to turn each measure (Deaths and Prevalence) into its own column with the `val` column being their respective row values:

```
location  | cause    |  Deaths  | Prevalence
Alabama  |sickness1 | 0.045    | 0.05
Alabama  |sickness2 | 0.001    | 0.003
...
```

Is there a (simple) way to do this? 
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a existing question that could help me but that might be because I'm not really sure how to look for it. So, if there are already existing questions (and answers) on similar matters, a quick pointer towards one of them would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `pivoting`, but regular `DataFrame.pivot` won't do it, because you need to use multiple columns as unique indexes: `location` and `cause`.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['measure'], values='val', index=['cause', 'location'], 
               aggfunc=max)
```

where `aggfunc` is how you want to handle data aggregation (`max`, `mean`, `sum`...), if there is only one value per row it doesn't matter.

```
measure             Deaths  Prevalence
cause     location
sickness1 Alabama    0.045       0.050
sickness2 Alabama    0.001       0.003
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much for the well explained answer!